# Rails + PostgreSQL -Using Like

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following two queries:

```
SELECT users.* FROM "users" WHERE (fname || lname LIKE '%james%')

SELECT users.* FROM "users" WHERE (fname || lname LIKE '%James%')
```

I have a record in the User Table with fname = James

The problem I'm having is the first query returns 0 results, and the 2nd returns the correct result.

I want the LIKE to be case insensitive. Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SELECT users.* FROM "users" WHERE (fname || lname ILIKE '%james%')`

ILIKE = case-insenstive LIKE. Note that this is specific to PostgreSQL, and not a SQL standard.

Comment: Thanks guys. I gave this the answer as it has an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
  SELECT users.* FROM "users" WHERE (fname || lname ILIKE '%james%')
```

Notice the 'I' in LIKE

Answer (score 0):

Queries with "LIKE" or "ILIKE" are pretty slow, especially for tables with many entries. I think it would be faster if you use the full text search ability of PostgreSQL.

[PostgreSQL textsearch docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch.html)