# PostgreSQL like not returning matching instances

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, pattern-matching, sql-like

How does the PostrgeSQL `like` function work? I'm using token inputs to limit input from user with only existing values.

I have the following values in the DB:

```
  `Yellow, White, Orange...`
```

My Code

```
 @colors = Color.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

If I type in `w` for example `White` is not proposed. I have to type in second letter to see White proposed. Because Db values all start by Capital letter I suspect a difference with SQLite.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258794/rails-postgresql-using-like) which mentions `ILIKE` but was wondering if there is some common code that work both with Postgres and SQLite.

Comment: Storing comma separated values is usually the sign of a questionable database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case-sensitivity of LIKE depends on the database you use. Some databases ignore case when using LIKE, some don't, some look at various configuration options. One way around this is to normalize the case yourself by converting to upper or lower case:

```
@colors = Color.where("lower(name) like ?", "%#{params[:q].downcase}%")
```

Answer (score 2):

The SQLite `LIKE` operator is case insensitive per default.
In PostgreSQL **`ILIKE`** is the case insensitive version of `LIKE`. There are also operators:

```
~~   .. LIKE
~~*  .. ILIKE
!~~  .. NOT LIKE
!~~* .. NOT ILIKE
```

These three expressions are all effectively the same in PostgreSQL:

```
name ilike '%w%'
name ~~*   '%w%'
lower(name) like lower('%w%')
```

The last line mostly **works in both** [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE). I added links to the respective manual pages.

A limitation applies: SQLite only understands lower / upper case of ASCII characters, while PostgreSQL understands other UTF-8 characters, too.

Comment: Thanks for the full Db explanation.